# agm-snazzy-info-window will close when Map is click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

But I don't want to close in map click please help. It has a property called `closeOnMapClick` but its not working,

```
<agm-snazzy-info-window  closeWhenOthersOpen="true" [isOpen]="i == selected ? markerFlag : false" [latitude]="list.Latitude"
[longitude]="list.Longitude" closeOnMapClick="false">
<template>

</template>
<agm-snazzy-info-window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing brakets around said property:

```
<agm-snazzy-info-window [closeWhenOthersOpen]="true" [isOpen]="i == selected ?
    markerFlag : false" [latitude]="list.Latitude"
    [longitude]="list.Longitude" [closeOnMapClick]="false">
    <template>
        <!-- Something -->
    </template>
<agm-snazzy-info-window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution

```
 <agm-map style="position: inherit; top: 10;width: 870px;height: 460px" [latitude]="Latitude" [longitude]="Longitude" [scrollwheel]="true"
                        [zoomControl]="true" [zoom]="zoom" [disableDefaultUI]="false" [mapTypeControl]="true" [zoomControl]="false" [clickableIcons]="false" [usePanning]="true">
                        <div id="marker" *ngFor="let list of maplistmarker, let i = index;">
                            <agm-marker [iconUrl]="list.ClarifiId == selected ?  './assets/images/markerorange.png' : './assets/images/marker.png'" *ngIf="list.ClarifiId"
                                [latitude]="list.Latitude" [longitude]="list.Longitude" (markerClick)="markerClick(i,list.Latitude,list.ClarifiId,list.minrate,list.miles)"
                                [zIndex]="list.ClarifiId == selected ? 1: -1">
```